# hadoop hdfs namenode format not work

Tags: hadoop

I'm a hadoop green hand, I try install hadoop3.0 in my vm, after I config hadoop, and then try :

```
hdfs namenode ‐format
```

and got output:

```
2017-12-26 00:20:56,255 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = localhost/127.0.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [‐format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 3.0.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /opt/hadoop-3.0.0/etc/hadoop:/opt/hadoop-3.0.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop-3.0.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar:   .............   hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-3.0.0.jar:/opt/hadoop-3.0.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-3.0.0.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r c25427ceca461ee979d30edd7a4b0f50718e6533; compiled by 'andrew' on 2017-12-08T19:16Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_151
************************************************************/
2017-12-26 00:20:56,265 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-12-26 00:20:56,269 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [‐format]
Usage: hdfs namenode [-backup] | 
        [-checkpoint] | 
        [-format [-clusterid cid ] [-force] [-nonInteractive] ] | 
        [-upgrade [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved<k-v pairs>] ] | 
        [-upgradeOnly [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved<k-v pairs>] ] | 
        [-rollback] | 
        [-rollingUpgrade <rollback|started> ] | 
        [-importCheckpoint] | 
        [-initializeSharedEdits] | 
        [-bootstrapStandby [-force] [-nonInteractive] [-skipSharedEditsCheck] ] | 
        [-recover [ -force] ] | 
        [-metadataVersion ]

2017-12-26 00:20:56,365 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at localhost/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

I config hdfs-site.xml as follow:

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/dan/hadoop_data/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/dan/hadoop_data/datanode</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

when I start namenode service, it fail and log tell :
2017-12-26 00:03:41,331 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
2017-12-26 00:03:41,337 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:

Can anyone tell me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Sometimes It happens. First, stop all service and just go to your `current` directory and delete `current` directory. Hadoop `current` directory stores all logs files as well. By removing `current` directory start all service again.

**Stop all service :**

`$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/stop-all.sh`

After stop all service once you should format Namenode by the following command.

**Format name node:**

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode –format`

Now again start all service by following command.

**Start all service:**

`$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh`

**Solution 2:**

Sometimes Namenode went into `safe-mode`. You need to leave safe node by following command.

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Comment: I did as follow， but it did not work:
dan@ubuntu:/opt/hadoop-3.0.0$ $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/stop-all.sh                 
WARNING: Stopping all Apache Hadoop daemons as dan in 10 seconds.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Stopping namenodes on [localhost]
Stopping datanodes
Stopping secondary namenodes [ubuntu]
Stopping nodemanagers
Stopping resourcemanager

dan@ubuntu:/opt/hadoop-3.0.0$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
safemode: Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

Comment: I reexecuted $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode –format, get the result the same as the post

Comment: Hi jAy PaTel, I removed dfs.namenode.name.dir and dfs.datanode.data.dir from hdfs-site.xml, and reformat, it seem to work, it showed:
2017-12-26 19:53:46,254 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-dan/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.

How can i change a dir instead of tmp? Thanks!

Comment: You have to make `temp` directory manually and give path into `hdfs-site.xml` and then give permissions to that particular directory. It will work.